# Rails - How to define setter/getter dynamically for list of methods inside a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, getter-setter

I have a Notifications module which have classes like 1)car 2)bike 3)Aeroplane. I have a serialized column in UserFeature model.And I have a module 'Notifications' which has list of 11 classes in it.

```
Notifications
 1)car
 2)bike
 3)Aeroplane
```

The hash structure of the column notifications in UserFeature model must be

```
 {:car => {:mirror => :true, :door => :true}
  :bike => {:x=> :true, :x => :true}
  :Aeroplane => {:p => :true, :q => :true}
 }
```

I can access user_object.Notifications
But so as to access user_object.car and also user_object.mirror I need to write getter/setter methods **{ Defining getter/setter dynamically because I dont want to write getter/setter for every method and also I am unsure about the number of methods I have -> which in future may extend }**

```
     Notifications.constants.each do |notification_class|
    class_methods = "Notifications::#{notification_class}".constantize.methods(false)
    class_methods.each do |method|
     method_name = method[0..-4].split('(')[0]
      setter_getter_name = "#{notification_class.to_s.underscore}_#{method_name}"

     define_method("#{setter_getter_name}=") do |value|
        self.notifications = GlobalUtils.form_hash(self.notifications, "#{notification_class}".to_sym, "#{method_name}".to_sym)
        self[:notifications]["#{notification_class}".to_sym][ "#{method_name}".to_sym]  = value
     end

    define_method("#{setter_getter_name}") do
       self.notifications.fetch("#{notification_class_name}".to_sym, {}).fetch("#{method_name}".to_sym)
     end

end
end
```

But still when i try to access user_object.mirror,

```
     undefined method for #<UserFeature000043645345>
```

What I am doing wrong?
I need to do this using getter/setter method only

Answer (score 0):

Use Ruby `OpenStruct` class. It will fulfill your requirements without defining such bunch of code.

Edit1, example:

```
require 'ostruct'

class Aeroplane < OpenStruct; end

a = Aeroplane.new(:p => :true, :q => :true)
a.p # => true
```

Answer (score 0):

An [`OpenStruct`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) is a data structure, similar to a Hash, that allows the definition of arbitrary attributes with their accompanying values. This is accomplished by using Ruby’s metaprogramming to define methods on the class itself.

example:

```
require 'ostruct'
hash = { "country" => "Australia", :population => 20_000_000 }
data = OpenStruct.new(hash)

p data        # -> <OpenStruct country="Australia" population=20000000>
```